# Share pdf file via my application on android

Tags: android, pdf, share

Hi I have to develop an application which should enable sharing of pdf files. I have to create a service wich puts my application as default for .PDF file sharing.[image: picture1][image: picture2] As you can see on the picture I can share the pdf via bluetooth/Gmail/Drive...etc. I need to put there my application to. How can it be done? thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Go here, then check

```
4.3. Example: Register an activity for the share intent
```

Comment: it is now under heading 3.2

Answer (score 4):

You need to register it as a reciever for the SEND action. An example is given [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intentfilter_shareintent). The mime type for pdf is 'application/pdf'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot force that, its totally on android system, thats why it pushes for a chooser with all the apps that has registered themselves as handler for specified data type, following which user can mark it as default or not.

Comment: How can I register my app as default handler ? That should solve my problem