# Register application in iOS as default pdf opener

Tags: ios, file, sharing

Hi I am developing an application which could share pdf files, I need to register my app to default pdf opener/distributor(sender) But I am not able to do that and I can not find that. I have read the movieStream example from apple, but I can not find the solution.

the question is similar as I questioned for android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653930/share-pdf-file-via-my-application-on-android)

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read: [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

Tutorial:
[Associate a File Type with your App](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/03/04/associate-a-file-type-with-your-ios-application.aspx)